# Multiple JS created twitter buttons : track which one was clicked?

Tags: javascript, events, twitter

I have multiple buttons (tweet, share...) on a page that a want to track for analytics. I want to know if the button A is better than the button B :)

The buttons are loaded "on demand" : on hover on certain divs, or after some time. I do it for performance reasons. I don't want the whole DOM to be parsed each time.

I use the twttr.widgets.createXXX functions from twitter widgets library, as explained here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events.

Everything works well until that.

But when I bind callback functions on the specified events, the callback data provided is empty, or almost. I have the button type, but I don't have any other info about the event and original target.

I looked inside window.twttr object, for infos relative to the last event or the differents iframes createds.

Here is the jsfiddle I made to explain the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/3fFFf/

```
<div id="btnContainer1" class="btn not-activated">Button container 1</div>
<div id="btnContainer2" class="btn not-activated">Button container 2</div>

<script>
    // Loading the twitter library
    twttr = (function (d,s,id) {  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id; js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } }); }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

    twttr.ready(function(twttr) {

        // I only want to load the tweet button when the divs are hovered
        $(document).on("mouseenter", ".btn.not-activated", function(e){
            var $div = $(this);
            $div.removeClass("not-activated").text("");

            twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
                "http://twitter.com",
                $div[0],
                function(el) {}, // loaded callback
                { // Options
                    lang: "en",
                    text: "hey, share this great site !",
                    via: "me",
                    count: "none"
                });
            })

            // A click occured on a twitter button
            twttr.events.bind('click', function(e){
                alert("e.target should by a node or something, but is : "+e.target)
            });

    });
</script>
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug:

[Why is data.target always null for a web intent tweet event?](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/20231)

[Issue #1220: data.target not set on the 'tweet' web intent event if the tweet button was created by createShareButton](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/1220)